# Codemirror autocomplete and auto closing brackets doesnt trigger change event

Tags: javascript, node.js, autocomplete, codemirror

I have the following problem. I've written a server and client scripts for node js that work as live collaboration code editing. 2 or more people can code in the same instance of CodeMirror editor. Until i have enabled autocomplete feature and auto closing brackets it was working perfect, but after i did it messed up the work. When you use autocomplete list or when bracket or tag will be closed by module not by you manually it will not be recognized as change. I have inspected an object that CodeMirror instance is returning and it doesnt contain change that have been done automatically. its not even strictly problem for node js beacuse if you want lets say, send changes to server via ajax and save in a file, it wont happen beacuse its not present in change object. Anyone had similiar problem and can help?

client code:

```
    var appCM = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('app-cm'), {
        mode: 'text/html',
        theme: "monokai",
        styleActiveLine: true,
        lineNumbers: true,
        matchBrackets: true,
        indentUnit: 4,
        indentWithTabs: true,
        autoCloseTags: true,
        autoCloseBrackets: true,
        matchTags: false,
        extraKeys: {
            "Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete",
            "Ctrl-Q": function(appCM) {
                appCM.foldCode(appCM.getCursor());
            }
        },
        foldGutter: true,
        gutters: ["CodeMirror-linenumbers", "CodeMirror-foldgutter"],
        readOnly: access
    });

        appCM.on('change', function(i, op) {
            socket.emit('change', op);
        });

        socket.on('change', function(data) {
            appCM.replaceRange(data.text, data.from, data.to);
        });
```

server code:

```
socket.on('change', function(op) {
    if(op.origin === '+input' || op.origin === 'paste' || op.origin === '+delete') {
        clients.forEach(function(client) {
            if(client !== socket)
                client.emit('change', op);
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are explicitly filtering out changes whose origin isn't one of input/paste/delete. Why are you doing that? You'll need to propagate all changes if you want peers to stay in sync.

Comment: thank you for puting me into right track, when i added those problem was fixed